# Simplifying a summation with VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Suppose there is an row like [100, 0.9, 50, 0.8, ...], I want to get a sum like 100×0.9+50×0.8+... Simply writing out each summation term seems very cumbersome for long rows, is there an easier way to write it? Here is what I have done so far. (Note the variables of each term are (D3, E3), (F3, G3),...)

```
=SUM(FLOOR(VLOOKUP(D3,Sheet!B2:C99,2,FALSE)*E3,1),FLOOR(VLOOKUP(F3,Sheet!B2:C99,2,FALSE)*G3,1),...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's mine:

`=LET(Array, WRAPROWS(A!:H!,2,0),SUMPRODUCT(CHOOSECOLS(Array,1),CHOOSECOLS(Array,2)))`

As noted in the comments my answer differs slightly because I had a different value in cell G1.

[image]

Explanation:

`LET` - variable creation in formulas for reability

`Array, WRAPROWS()` - set variable Array to be a conversion (wraprows) of 1x8 matrix to 4x2 matrix

`SUMPRODUCT` - multiplies and sums arrays

`CHOOSECOLS()` - formula to take subset of array; also can use `INDEX()`

Comment: Your formula is correct, you're just using a different input (92 instead of 95)

Comment: @gns100 could you put your formula as text so the readers do not need to retype but can copy paste?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

=LET(r,$A3:$H3,
f,LAMBDA(start,CHOOSECOLS(r,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(r)/2,start,2))),
SUMPRODUCT(f(1),f(2))
)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using figures supplied by @FlexYourData.

`=SUM(BYCOL($A$1:$H$1,LAMBDA(arr,arr*OFFSET(arr,,1)*ISODD(COLUMN(arr)))))`
Problem with this one is that the `OFFSET` uses one more column than the original range so you can't put the formula in the next column across.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using older formula for those without office 365:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:G1,B1:H1*ISODD(COLUMN($A$1:INDEX($1:$1,COLUMNS(A1:G1)))))
```

The key here is to have two ranges that are offset by 1.  One would only change the `A1:G1` and `B1:H1` references in the formula to include their data.  the `$A$1` and `$1:$1` should be left as is.  These are counters and it must start at column 1 for it to work properly.

[image]